# Installing Ubuntu on a harddrive that is already partitioned with Vista and win10

Tags: system-installation

So I'm really new to Ubuntu and I would like to **replace** my vista OS with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.(Or 15.04 if that would be easier)

My hard drive has 2 partitions with 2 different operating systems currently (vista and win 10). I don't know if this makes the process different.

My Vista is completely bare, I've uninstalled everything and deleted every file that is not needed to run, I'm not worried about losing anything on this side of the partition.

Essentially I want to delete vista and install Ubuntu as the new operating system (much like installing a new version of windows). I keep seeing the  procedure as: Install as a new partition, delete operating system, then delete partition that said operating system was on". Is there any other way?

Also how advanced is this task? Can a beginner manage within the next week or will it take some reading?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Your question is almost certainly going to be closed as a duplicate;  you should try doing some searching before asking a question.  A likely candidate is http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I figured there maybe something out there, but 2 things: 
1.The question you posted is about windows 8 without a currently partitioned drive, so it may give some insight but still not what I'm looking for.
2. I'm not well versed, so a lot of what I read wasn't making too much sense, should I just keep chugging on and learning (is this task that advanced?)

Comment: Install is easy, just follow the directions and be careful when partitioning,  it seems daunting, but the Ubuntu installer is the best around, very simple very straight forward. Even though it is for Windows 8 it works the same for 10. Vista too Ubuntu, the only extra step is to delete the vista partition, in the installer choose `something else` option highlight vista and click the - button, now you have blank a space and can carry on following the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about some dual booting tutorials about Ubuntu. Well, I guess that when asking you about partitions, you should choose the 'something else' option and pick the vista partition there. Set it as root ( / ) and pick the ext4 file system.

Comment: Does dual booting referring to the menu to select which operating system? (Sorry i really don't know much, trying to learn)

Comment: Yes. It is the same thing you had with Windows 10 and Vista until now.